# React Native : Conditional render() based on AsyncStorage result

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Trying to use a AsyncStorage variable to conditionally render content.

My app uses `createBottomTabNavigator` from `react-navigation`. I have a tab called **Settings** that must conditionally render content based on wether a user is logged in or not (checking AsyncStorage). The following code works on first render but another tab can update AsyncStorage value, returning back to **Settings** tab it still renders initial content.

Which approach can i use to achieve this, i'm also trying to use **shouldComponentUpdate** but i'm not sure how it works.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 

class Settings extends React.Component{

constructor(props){ 
  super(props);  
  this.state = { 
    isLoggedIn:false
  }; 
}

//I want to use this method but not sure how.
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
 // return this.state.isLoggedIn != nextState; 
}

componentDidMount(){
  console.log("componentWillUpdate..");
  this.getLocalStorage();
}

getLocalStorage = async () => {
  try { 
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');  
    if(value !== null) {
      this.setState({isLoggedIn:true});
    } 
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}

render() {   
    if(this.state.isLoggedIn)
    {
      return( 
          <View>
              <Text style={styles.title_header}>Logged In</Text>
          </View>  
      );
    }
    else{
      return( 
          <View>
              <Text style={styles.title_header}>Logged Out</Text>
          </View> 
      );
    }  
 }
}

export default Settings;

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html). Add event listeners to your `Settings` components.

> onWillFocus - event listener
>
> onDidFocus - event listener
>
> onWillBlur - event listener
>
> onDidBlur - event listener

for example, the following will get fired when the next screen is focused.

```
focusSubscription = null;

onWillFocus = payload => {
    // get values from storage here
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.focusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    this.onWillFocus
  );
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this.focusSubscription && this.focusSubscription.remove();
  this.focusSubscription = null;
};
```

Comment: I am in Centurion area sir/madam, and yourself?

Comment: in Johannesburg/Alex.

Comment: Wow, not very far from here. I don't know Alex that well. We should link up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from react-navigation `createBottomTabNavigator`. On first visit, the component is mounted and so `componentDidMount` is called and everything is great.

However, when you switch tab, the component is **not unmounted**, which means that when you come back to the tab there won't be any new call to `componentDidMount`.

What you should do is add a listener to the `willFocus` event to know when the user switches back to the tab.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.listener = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('username').then((value) => {
      if (value !== null) {
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
      }
      catch(e) {
        // error reading value
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Don't forget to remove the listener when the component is unmounted:

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.listener.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a detailed answer, helped me understand the lifecycle more.